# Communication between electron and rust desktop app

Tags: node.js, rust, process, electron, communication

I'm currently building application which consists of multiple parts:

- Service that doing some operations with OS API (currently its only Windows), and stores some data within SQLite database. This service is written in Rust
- Service that calculates values by demand or schedule, looking for values in database. (This service is currently runs in same executable as 1st one, I'm not sure if I really need to separate them, but their job is really different)
- Electron application which displays data

I want to add to 2nd service functionality that will allow him to share database/calculated data. How can I make this service and electron application to communicate?
I know that I can achieve this via HTTP connections or queue (like redis or something), but for me it seems like overhead. Are there any other methods for this?

Comment: Really the most straightforward thing is to just make your service into a local http server and you can just send it requests from your electron app and get data back.  http requests are trivial these days to code and use and I wouldn't worry about the overhead unless you're making thousands of requests a second.  You could also use a webSocket and then figure out what to use for a request/response format, but unless you want the service to be able to automatically send updates to your Electron app, you don't need a webSocket for this purpose.

Comment: @jfriend00, I see. Thank you for reminding me about websockets! I think I will go with them, because I will have functionality for which ws might be really handy